# How to create an app for Windows XP using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I have very little knowledge on apps for Desktop.

I created a Simple app for Windows 8 using the free Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 (in C#, XAML).

Now I am wanting that app to run on other Windows platforms like Windows XP, Windows 7 etc. I understand, that Metro apps can't run on Windows 7 or XP, but All I want is stripped down version of my app which runs on Windows 7 and XP as well.

I am looking for options like Project->News->Target Windows XP... I also have another question, Can we use XAML,.CS approach even for Windows XP.

How can I port my existing Windows 8 app to WIndows XP, 7 with minimal effort and using C# and making use of current set up ( Visual Studio Express 2012) ?

Comment: How do I do that? Where Should I change the configuration in VS Express 2012 for Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all choose **.Net Framework 4.0** as a target framework.
(This window appears after clicking create new project)

[image]

You can either choose **WPF** application or **Windows Forms** Application. But WPF is recommended if you know how to work with .Xaml

Comment: Thanks for posting this Image... I clicked on "New Project" under templates->Visual C#, I can see just "Windows Store" .. How can I see all options? Should I install Something additional to get those options?

Comment: @ChethanThimmappa You can create only Windows 8 apps with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. If you are student you can download VS 2012 Professional from Dreamspark. https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=44

Comment: I wish I was a Student :( But I really wanted to do an app for Windows XP/ Windows 7.. The thing is the app has come out well in Windows 8.. I want to show it to a client, and they dont have Windows 8... The purpose is to show a solution for their problem. But I m struck with platform Issue.. Wish a single IDE (Express edition) could have handled all platforms...

Comment: Then you can download 90-day trial of Visual Studio Ultimate 2012  from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads

Comment: Thank you very much. Will download now.

Comment: @ChethanThimmappa :) ok. Do not forget to mark as answer if it would help after downloading.

Comment: Lex Li answer is more appropriate.. "download and install a special edition of Visual Studio 2012 Express, named for Windows Desktop" ... downloading that now... as it is available for more than 90 days.. what say?

Comment: The Download is in progress... I am going to create my first XP app, using WPF as you have mentioned!!! Thanks

Comment: @ChethanThimmappa Yes, you can use that version also. But, it is only for Desktop applications. I am glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get your app to run on Windows 7 and Windows 8 you need to:

1. To set your Target to .Net 4.0.

   File->New->Project

   At the top of the dialog there is a list that allows you to select the framework.

   [see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx)
2. Make sure the .Net 4.0 Framework is installed on the machines you wish to deploy to.

   [see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
3. If you want the framework to distribute with your app so you don't have to install the framework on each machine,

   [see this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733).

Comment: Try to add the important information from each link to your answer. If the links ever go stale, your answer will still be useful.

Answer (score 2):

To develop applications for Windows XP or similar, you need to download and install a special edition of Visual Studio 2012 Express, named for Windows Desktop,

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/09/12/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop-is-here.aspx

Don't use the so called "[for Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8)", as that can only create Windows Store Apps.