# System limitations of "XAML" and "C#"

Tags: c#, xaml

I am new to "XAML" and "C#". Will I be able to write application running on Windows xp, 7, 8, 8.1, 10 in C#/XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your application, use Net Framework 4.0.

See this post :

[How to create an app for Windows XP using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627628/how-to-create-an-app-for-windows-xp-using-visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows)